# VS Code setting to collapse activity bar on focus change

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Couldn't find an answer on here or elsewhere.
It's just a convenience feature that I would use. I prefer to use the screen space on split editors, and it would save me the effort of manually closing the activity bar.

Comment: You could make a macro to close the side bar whenever you split a file.  Interested in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that is a feature that VS Code has implemented. Feel free to reach out to the developers on GitHub here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

In the meantime, you can create a hotkey that will hide the activity bar.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+b",
  "command": "workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility"
},
```